# why my native library is not loaded?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I have added the Gradle tag to this thread since I feel my build.gradle file is missing a needed configuration. Below is a copy of my file. The issue I am having is I don't know why my shared library files do not make it into my apks. And I think I see the tell tell signs of what I need in this file from reading the Gradle manual but I want to be sure.

```
sansari@ubuntu:~/AndroidStudioProjects/ThirdNDK/app$ more build.gradle 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sansari.thirdndk"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk
                {
                    moduleName "HelloJNI"
                }
    }
    sourceSets.main
            {
                jni.srcDirs = [] // ndk-build.cmd needs to be invoked from command line
                jniLibs.srcDirs '/src/main/libs'
            }
    productFlavors
            {
                x86
                        {
                            ndk
                                    {
                                        abiFilter "x86"
                                    }
                        }

    armv7a
            {
                ndk
                        {
                            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
                        }
            }
                arm {
                    //flavorDimension "abi"
                    ndk
                            {
                                abiFilter "armeabi"
                                versionCode = 1;
                            }
                    }
            }
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

I am trying a native code project in Android Studio, and I get the following error. But I don't know why the loader is looking in that directory. Or why the folder is called com.example.sansari.thiredndk-1. I just called my project thirdndk. I am not sure how -1 is added. I wanted to know how can I fix this, and learn why the loader is looking in that directory? My /libs folder is in the main directory of the project.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load HelloJNI from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.sansari.thirdndk-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.sansari.thirdndk-1]: findLibrary returned null
```

@Preethi. Thanks; I'll have a look. I typed it rather quickly.

@Preethi or anyone else; I don't seem to have any luck with this. Here is the apk:

Thank you all for your help. It finally worked. I googled "how to add library files to apk with gradle", and this little gem came up: "Include .so library in apk in android studio [duplicate]" It is on stackoverflow. I am not sure if I have permission to post urls yet. In it, there was comments about a bug in earlier versions of Gradle for including libraries. One of the links in it had a comment about using the jniLibs folder as the directory to put shared libraries in. So I took a chance and copied all of my shared libraries files from libs to jniLibs. I created jniLibs and copied the files and voila. Thank you again to all of you. You guys rock.

Comment: this usually happens if something is wrong in your android.mk file

Comment: do you get any errors when you run ndk-build?

Comment: The folder name with `-1` is beyond your control, and perfectly OK. The file you show us is your **Android.mk**, and except for the comments, it looks fine. But you are using *Android Studio*, which does not have full NDK integration. Why do you think your native code is compiled at all?

Comment: Good, you have the libs built. Now the question is if they got packed into the APK. Just use `unzip -l` on the APK file to check that.

Comment: If a custom shared library is not in your APK, then it definitely won't be loaded at runtime.  Focus on figuring out why it isn't making it into the package.

Answer (score 3):

if your .so files are now generated inside `libs/<abi>`, the only remaining step is to make Android Studio integrate these files from the `libs` folder.

By default, it looks for .so files inside `jniLibs`, but you can change it so integrates the files from your `libs` folder:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem.
The apk used to build correctly in Ubuntu but in Windows the apk missed lib folder.

Apparently the mistake was naming of `jniLibs` folder. I had named it as `jnilibs` all in lowercase which was causing problem. I had corrected it to jniLibs and apk was building correctly on windows.

Hope this helps.